# How to compare negative numbers (2's complement) in verilog?

Tags: comparison, verilog

I have the following comparison statement in verilog, which works fine (positive comparison)

```
if((count_cc >= 13'b0000000011110)&&(count_cc <= 13'b0000000111100)) //30,60
begin
level=4'b0010; //level 2
end
```

However, when I use 2's complement, it does not work,

```
if((count_cc >= 13'b1111111100100)&&(count_cc <= 13'b1111111110110)) //-10 , -28
begin
level=4'b0101;  //level 5
end
```

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `count_cc` is already declared signed, use

```
if((count_cc >= 13'sb1111111100100)&&(count_cc <= 13'sb1111111110110)) //-10 , -28
begin
  level=4'b0101;  //level 5
end
```

of course, this would also work

```
if((count_cc >= -10)&&(count_cc <= -28)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have count_cc declared as: input [12:0] count_cc; do I need to declare it as input signed  [12:0] count_cc;?

Comment: Yes. But realize you can now only express a 12-bit positive number.

Comment: I tried with signed and the direct number (-10,-28) , still, it does not work. Any other suggestions? I use it in a Verilog-AMS environment (with analog and digital signals), not sure if it does matter.

Comment: if any of the operands is unsigned, verilog will treat all of them as unsigned. So, make sure that count_cc is signed as well as others. `reg signed  [12:0] count_cc`. You can also use `$signed` for casting.

Comment: @Serge That helped. Actually I was using it normally (13'b00..) instead of (13'sb00..) for positive values. Now after using (13'sb..) for all values it works correct. Thanks very much.